# Sql Server query executes insert twice instead of once

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, navicat

I am running a sql query

```
INSERT INTO Items(ID,Name) VALUES (1,'test')
INSERT INTO ItemsExtended(LanguageId,ItemId,IsMain,Name,IsVerified) VALUES (1,1,1,'test',1)
```

the first statement fails with:

```
[Err] 23000 - [SQL Server]Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Items__3214EC2766F4E086'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Items'. The duplicate key value is (1).
01000 - [SQL Server]The statement has been terminated.
```

because of primary key, but the second statement runs twice. so there are 2 inserts instead of just one on the second insert. if the first statement does not fails the second statement inserts only once as it should. why does it happens? there are no triggers on the tables.

Comment: What are you looking at that makes you think the statement ran twice?

Comment: the ItemsExtended table, order by id (identity) desc

Comment: those querys are run by you or by another program?

Comment: by me, using navicat to send the query.

Comment: can you run it on sql server management studio?

Comment: This is likely the due to the application (navicat) executing the batch again following an exception.  I suggest you try SSMS as Felipe suggested.

Comment: you are right, the problem is in navicat for some reason.  sql server management studio runs it as it should.

Comment: I would put these two queries in a stored procedure and wrap them in a try/catch with a transaction so you can rollback when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in navicat for some reason it executed it twice, running in sql server management studio worked just fine.